# linq select date range between month

Tags: c#, linq

I've a list of dates below:

```
List<Datetime> listOfDates = new List<DateTIme>();

listofDates.add(new DateTime(2012,01,04));
listofDates.add(new DateTime(2012,01,05));
listofDates.add(new DateTime(2012,01,06));
..
listofDates.add(new DateTime(2012,01,31));
listofDates.add(new DateTime(2012,02,01));
..
listofDates.add(new DateTime(2012,02,28));
listofDates.add(new DateTime(2012,03,01));
..
listofDates.add(new DateTime(2012,03,16));
```

I need to filter the above list by month range as below:

```
var filterdListByMonth = listofDates.Where(x.DateTime.Month => 1 and x.DateTime.Month <=2).ToList();
```

But this doesn't seem to return right result. Could someone please help?

Comment: Am I missing something or it would be more like `var filterdListByMonth = listofDates.Where(dt => dt.Month => 1 && dt.Month <=2).ToList();` ?

Comment: Maybe you should use `>=`, not `=>`, as *greater or equal* operator, shouldn't you?

Answer (score 4):

If you fix the compiler errors it works as expected:

```
List<DateTime> listOfDates = new List<DateTime>();
listOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 01, 04));
listOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 01, 05));
listOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 01, 06));
listOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 01, 31));
listOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 02, 01));
listOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 02, 28));
listOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 03, 01));
listOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 03, 16));
var filterdListByMonth = listOfDates.Where(date => date.Month >= 1 && date.Month <= 2);

// Outputs each date except the two in March.
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, filterdListByMonth));
```